# Handling metro event in native c++ class

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I would like to handle a button clicked event in a native c++ class.  I have tried creating a 'handler' object derived from `Object` to handle the event and then calling a c++ method.  For example I tried the following code:

```
ref class GButtonHandler sealed : public Object
 {
 public:
     void Button_Click(Object^ sender, RoutedEventArgs^ e)
     {
     }

    GTextBlockHandler(GButtonImpl * pButtonImpl, Button ^ button)
     {
         button->Click += ref new RoutedEventHandler(this, &GTextBlockHandler::Button_Click);
     }
 };
```

Thinking that I could squirrel away the `pButtonImpl` pointer and then use it to call a native function in the `Button_Clicked` function.  However on compiling this code, I get the error:

```
error C3986: '{ctor}': signature of public member contains native type 'GButtonImpl'
```

So it seems that it does not like me passing in native classes into an ref object.  Is there a way to do this?

Note that I am completely new to developing Metro style apps, so bear with me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it all makes sense to me now.  For anyone else who is interested, the reason you cannot have WinRT Objects with public functions that have native C++ arguments is that these objects would then not be consumable by non C++ code.  However, the (obvious?) solution is to make the constructor private and have the class that creates the Object declared as a 'friend' class (duh!).  Then all is well, the compiler is happy, and I am happy.

Thanks to all who took the time to read this.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is to use `internal` rather than `public` for the constructor. This tells the compiler that it will only be available in the current project, and won't be available to external projects (i.e. a library written in another language).